# Regular expression for getting HREF based on span tag

Tags: java, regex, html-parsing, href, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression for getting HREF from footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833105/regular-expression-for-getting-href-from-footer)

I want to get the HREF tag of a specific span tag. In Java what is the regular expression for it.

If there are 10 Span tags with values one, two , three etc...

What would be the regular expression for getting the HREF value of a span tag with value "three"

I need it in Java.